# Git Plugin parameter for branch and repository urls?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, branch, jenkins

I'm trying to use the Folders Plugin from Cloudbees to set a "fork" and "branch" environment variable for a folder.  That way, when developers create feature branches, they can copy the folder, update the two environment variables at the folder level, and then have CI jobs for their branches.

I can't seem to get the Git Plugin to use variables for the "repository url" and "branch" configuration options.  If I setup a parameterized job, that works fine, but not from the folders plugin or envinject plugin.

Anyone gotten this to work?